# Is there a way to access HttpRequest type inside a @Controller method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, httprequest

I have tried to find the answer to this, but I cannot seem to find what I am looking for. So I apologize if this question already exists.

**PROBLEM:** 
I want to be able to access the request type of a request inside of a generic method within my Controller.

**DESCRIPTION:** 
Using Spring ROO and Spring MVC, I have developed a small web service that will respond with certain tidbits from a database when queried. In one of my controller classes, I have some methods that handle some variety of GET, PUT, POST, etc., for the URIs that are mapped within the @RequestMapping parameter.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.Get, value = "/foo/bar")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getFooBar() {
    // stuff
}
```

If a request is made to the web service that it is not currently mapped, a 405 error is returned (which is correct), but I want to return more information along with a 405 response. Maybe respond with something like:

"I know you tried to execute a [some method], but this path only handles [list of proper methods]."

So I wrote a short method that only has the RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar")
```

I have found that the method with this mapping will catch all unhandled request types. But I am having trouble accessing the information of the request, specifically the type, from within the method.

**QUESTION:** 
A. How can I access the request type from within the method? 
 OR 
B. Is this the right approach? What would be the right approach?

**EDIT** 
**ANSWER:**

I added a `HttpServletRequest`object to the method parameters. I was able to access the method type from that.

I tried using `HttpRequest`, but it didn't seem to like that much.

Thanks all!

Comment: I guess just declaring a method parameter of type `HttpRequest` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method parameter of `HttpServletRequest`, but I think you'd be better off continuing to  reply with 405. A client should then make an HTTP OPTIONS call (see [How to handle HTTP OPTIONS with Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521690/how-to-handle-http-options-with-spring-mvc)) and you can return the list of allowed methods there.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use HttpEntity<>, but it did not have the information I needed. I will look into implementing an OPTIONS request, but I didnt mean to imply that I would stop replying with a 405. I just want to send more information along with the 405. This request is just meant to be a fallback request in case they dont hit anything else. Also, it didnt seem to like `HttpRequest`, but it liked `HttpServletRequest`

Comment: @Vae you're right, it should be `HttpServletRequest`, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

A. you can access request if you mentioned it as parameter in controller method

```
public ... getFooBar(HttpRequest request) {
...
}
```

B. you do not need to add any other description as the 405 status is descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to "A", just add "HttpRequest req" as an additional argument to your controller methods. Spring will automatically inject a reference to the request, and you can play with headers to your heart's content.

In answer to "B" - "What would be the right approach", how about this?

In order to return that 405, Spring has raised a MethodArgumentNotValidException. You can provide custom handling for this like so:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public MyMethodArgumentMessage handleMathodArgumentNotValidException(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    MyMethodArgumentMessage myMessage = 
            new MyMethodArgumentMessage(result.getFieldErrors());
    return myMessage;
}
```

You should take a look at the @ExceptionHandler annotation. This lets you add methods such as the following to your controller. You can define your own exceptions and appropriate custom handlers for them. I use it to return well-structured XML and JSON from REST services. Although for it to work, you need to throw specific exceptions from your controller methods.

A good walk-through of using this was provided by Petri Kainulkainen in his blog:
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/

Comment: btw - Petri Kainulainen wrote a good blog post on this here: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/