# SpringBoot CORS Filter not applied

Tags: spring, cors, spring-boot

I'm actually working on a SrpingBoot back end.

To resolve the CORS problem I use the simple filter that we can find everywhere.

```
@Component
public class CORSResponseFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse) resp;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

This filtre is add to the configuration here :

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfiguration() {
        super();

        // Create a recursive package scanner
        PackageNamesScanner resourceFinder = new PackageNamesScanner(
                new String[] { "X.service" }, true);
        // Register the scanner with this Application
        registerFinder(resourceFinder);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        // Mise en place du filtre
        register(CORSResponseFilter.class);
    }
}
```

But I still got this error :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What did I missed ?

Comment: Just add it as a bean to your configuration....

Comment: Problem solve. The request wasn't done on the good port. Thanks for having anwsered.

Comment: @Apédémak If your problem is solved, can you write an answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered?

Comment: I'll, I just can't validate before 2 days.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Trouble with port, nothing to do with the code.

Comment: Well, I can't remember exactly the problem but I know that my code works fine. This error was due to a conflit between 2 ports and the client didn't reach my back-end serveur. Thus my filter wasn't apply.

Comment: My problem is also solved, I needed to handle HTTP OPTIONS request (preflight request) in my controller!

Comment: @mohi How did you handle the preflight request?

Comment: @Jayraj maybe this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521690/how-to-handle-http-options-with-spring-mvc 
I had some similar method in the controller for OPTIONS request