# How deactivate CORS in a Spring Boot API (Version 2.2.6)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I am currently working on a React Front-End with an already existing Spring Boot Backend.

When developing locally i ran into the typicall CORS Error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8180/api/data/firms' from
origin 'https://localhost:8087' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

runtime.js:98 GET http://localhost:8180/api/data/firms net::ERR_FAILED
```

I already tried most of the solutions mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697883/can-you-completely-disable-cors-support-in-spring) however nothing really helped. By adding one of these snippets

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    }
```

```
@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilterRegistrationBean() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
  }
```

or creating a CorsFilter the CORS Error was gone but now the API always returned a HTTP 500 Error.

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your controller class.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "${cross.origin}")
@RestController
```

application.properties

```
cross.origin=https://localhost:8087
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70028838/4506703) for Spring Boot.

Additionally, if you are using `create-react-app`, you will avoid CORS problem to [set up proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).
(In this case, it is not required to change Spring Boot settings.)

`package.json`:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8180",
```