# Angular is not receiving the status code set by HttpServletResponse.sendErro() method in spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, api

I am sending an unauthorized status code (401) with a message if the user is not logged in spring boot application, the process works fine if we test it with the postman, however, it does not work with angular.

For example:

**there is an API**

```
http://localhost:8080/api/alarms?page=0&size=20
```

**Postman:**

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-05-08T09:40:52.454+00:00",
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/api/alarms"
}
```

**Angular:**

if we call the same API from the angular application, it gives the error but the error message and status codes are not the same

```
{
"headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
},
"status": 0,
"statusText": "Unknown Error",
"url": "http://localhost:8080/api/alarms?page=0&size=20",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/alarms?page=0&size=20: 0 Unknown Error",
"error": {
    "isTrusted": true
}
```

}

**Server-side code:**

```
    @Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "unauthorized");
}
```

How to catch the status code and message specified on the sever-side in the angular application?

Comment: I suspect you are having a Cors error. Inspect the network console in your browser.

Comment: @MikeOne no, the error in the network tab is clear, it shows the status of 401, but it does not have the response body, I mean the response body in the network tab is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

The problem was actually CORS problem, to solve the issue u can refer to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56133048/8985718)

Answer (score 0):

To catch the status code and message specified on the sever-side in the angular application, you can handle this using HTTP Interceptor in your angular application to handle all the global errors in your application.

Please refer to the below links

[Http interceptor for global error handling](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-http-error-handling/)

[Another link for global error handling](https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/handling-global-http-errors-using-interceptors-in-angular)