# Deploying my app on Heroku and getting a 403 on POST on my frontend but everything is fine on Postman

Tags: spring, heroku, postman, http-status-code-403

I deployed my app on Heroku and everything is online. I have 2 apps in Heroku, a frontend and a backend. The backend is a Spring Boot API and the frontend is React.

When I use Postman on the routes everything is ok, I can POST and GET. But on my frontend on Heroku, GET is OK but POST returns a 403 error. I don't get why because on Postman even on POST I don't need a token or anything.

I've set a Procfile for my API and my frontend. Every controller has a crossorigin. I don't know what file to paste here since I can't even begin to know where the error is coming from and since it deployed correctly to Heroku. I browsed every discussions regarding the subject on Stack Overflow without finding something working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post your Spring configuration. Do you have a CorsWebFilter configured for your project? Or better yet, do you have a Github repo where your code is hosted? If you give a link to that I can take a quick look.

Comment: yes here's the link to the backend
https://github.com/Jtaraconat/mercadonia

Comment: Looking at it now. In the meantime please update your postgres credentials immediately before some scummy hacker starts abusing that. And you probably want to change the value of that with an environment variable so you don't have to hard-code secrets in your git repo.

Comment: oh you're right i forgot to change it back to variable 
thanks!

Comment: Are all POST requests failing? Or just some of them? What about your PUT endpoints?

Comment: on the front end i can only test one POST route, the rest are authenticated,  in postman all POST are working and i didn't test for PUT.
I'll give it a try and update here

Comment: Studied your code a bit. One thing I noticed is that in your white list you mention for example "categories", but on your newCategory function you have this annotation: @PostMapping("/category") (so with "category", which is not mentioned in your white list). Also probably don't want to disable CORS altogether, yet set up a permissive policy, for example like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76029997/718849 and then get rid of the CorsConfigurationSource bean.

Comment: Which POST endpoint is the one giving you problems? That could help narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I only focused on /login, so at this point I don't know if I'll have the same issue one the other endpoint
I figured i needed cors i disabled it to see if it was causing the issue
I'll take a look at the discussion thank you for looking into it

Comment: And I forgot to mention that everything was working as intended on localhost and a local postgredb 
the db now is the heroku postgre addon
and i can POST GET with postman and the query are ok with pgadmin

Comment: Please be aware that just updating your git repo replacing the credentials in the file is not enough, your database credentials are now in your git history: https://github.com/Jtaraconat/mercadonia/commit/c63f8dd6c3dc3766872d7cf0f92205382301db6f  So please really change the credentials to prevent some automated script to abuse your database as I'm sure there are scripts automatically scraping Github and harvesting credentials from there which are accidentally committed.

Comment: you're right, just did it 
I forgot since I usually have my git on private
thank you again