# External script (CORS) Problem in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, vaadin

I'm trying to include an external JS-Script into my page using a script tag. To include the script, I used a VaadinServlet Bean to register a BootstrapListenery, which is able to append the script to the body with `response.getDocument().body().append()`.

But when I load the page, I get the error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". Because the script is located on a different domain, it can't be included into the page due to CORS-policy.

I already tried a ton of stuff, to allow the external script to be loaded. I tried to set the required headers in the `setAccessControlHeaders` method of the VaadinServlet, as it is done [here](https://gist.github.com/samie/9dcf26a6fbc034294e40). I tried to add a Bean to the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.19.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/cors.html). I tried adding `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")` to my Controller. And I've tried adding `http.cors().and().csrf().disable();` to the configure method of my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913846/cors-with-spring-boot-2).

But I just can't make it happen. I would appreciate any suggestions on what else I could try or on what I am doing wrong here. Also I can't really find a way to debug this.

Answer (score 3):

The CORS headers need to be set on the server that is serving the external script, not on your Vaadin app.